# Magento: How to insert a PHP call in the description of a product editor

Tags: php, magento, wysiwyg

I have a the following code

`<?php echo Mage::helper('stockstatus')->getListStatus(01); ?>`

This code returns me the stock status of a specific product. It works great when i insert it in a .phtml file in magento.

But i want to use it also in the description of a product. The thing is that it doesn't return me anything if i put this code in the description of a product. On the front end it just shows the actual code.

My question is how to make it work when inserting in the description editor of a product?
Please help

Comment: No. Editors should never, ever, EVER evaluate PHP. Just, No.

Comment: Ok, then i won't put PHP in the editor. Can you suggest me an alternative solution then? I just need to somehow get the stock status of specific products in the description. Maybe there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's really an ideal solution here - you *could* use str_replace in the .phtml file on some specific string like [[stock_status]].

```
$description = $_product->getDescription();
$description = str_replace('[[stock_status]]', Mage::helper('stockstatus')->getListStatus($_product->getId()), $description);
```

Problem with this though is that if you were to use the product description anywhere else you'd either keep having to do the string replace, or end up with these tags in your description.

Comment: Is there any way to use this code <?php echo Mage::helper('stockstatus')->getListStatus(01); ?> in a CMS block? or maybe in a widget?

Comment: Unfortunately not - the PHP entered into a WYSIWYG will be parsed as text, and not run on the server.